# Multi-type storage array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, storage

I'm programming a game in **python3.6**. There is some **pawns** on the board which are instance of the class 'pawn'. There is also **boulders** on the board which are instance of the class boulder. I just want to store these pawns and boulders in an **array**, like a numpy.array.

I have 2 problems :

- There is different type of object in the array, which is not possible with a numpy.array
- How can I represent an empty cell on my board, because I can't use an object, which has not the same type as the others.

How can I solve these two problems ? Is there already an object which can represent grid, an array and which accepts different type ?

Comment: Why not just use a list of lists?

Comment: "I just want to store these pawns and boulders in an array, like a numpy.array." But why? Why would you want to use a `numpy.ndarray` here, which are specialized data-structures for holding typed-multi-dimensional arrays? You could use a structured array,  but again, why? What benefit do you get over using a normal `list` with normal python objects? Are you trying to represent N-dimensional chessboards with potentially millions of rows/slices? IOW, yes there is already an object that does that, it's called a `list`

Comment: An alternative to a list of lists, is a dictionary.  That could be better if a lot of the board is empty.

Comment: Note, you *could* use a `numpy` array with `dtype=object`, but again, why not just use a list at that point? A numpy dtype=object array is basically a less useful python `list`

Comment: @hpaulj I mean, maybe if we were running on some technology from the 70's and the board was not a standard chessboard... otherwise, why would one care?

Comment: For a chess size board, storage efficiency isn't an issue.  But display and search efficiencies still matter.  An array, object or otherwise, is good for display purposes, but not that good for searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.dtype(object)`: `np.array(board, dtype=np.dtype(object))`

As for empty cells: just set them to `None`.

---

**Edit**: as some people have suggested, you might not need a numpy array at all. A list of lists or a dict with tuple indexes might solve your problem just fine and remove the overhead of using numpy.

Comment: why? Why not use a `list`??? A `numpy.ndarray` with dtype=object is essentially a less performant / useful python `list`

Comment: He asked about numpy arrays, and it's possible to use them. So why not?

But yeah, lists should work just fine too.

Comment: If someone asks how to shoot themselves in the foot, one should generally say "don't shoot yourself in the foot, instead, do <a better alternative>"

Comment: `numpy` arrays also allow for more flexible indexing, and have some functionality beyond what standard lists provide.

Comment: @user2699 what functionality would be relevant for a 8x8 chessboard of Python objects??? This makes no sense. You shouldn't be encouraging people to use the wrong tool.

Comment: Well, say you have an array `t = np.zeros((3, 3))`, how would you do the following with lists: ` t[0,0]` or `t[:, 3]` or `t[[1,3]]`.  `list` has no concept of dimensions, so for anything with more than one dimension I would say `list`s are the wrong datatype.

Comment: @user2699 `t[0][0]`, `t[r[3] for r in t]`, and `t[1],t[3]`. And no, `numpy.ndarray` objects are specialized for *numeric* data types and vectorized calculations on *very large* arrays. Otherwise, all this is probably slower and less memory efficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, if you want to improvise something with list comprehensions every time you need to index a list of lists, be my guest. I'll use a tool that's built to handle multidimensional data.

Comment: @user2699 generally, *one would write a function / class* with a useful interface and re-use it, not "improvise" every time. That's sort of part and parcel of software engineering. If you want to use `numpy`, a very heavy dependency requiring things like BLAS to represent an 8x8 grid *less efficiently* than a built-in data structure, just to use fancy indexing, then go ahead I guess.